# Mapsforge Mapfile-writer plugin not working with osmosis

Tags: java, openstreetmap, mapsforge, osmosis

I am trying to use the mapsforge mapfile-writer plugin with osmosis to compile my own map, but I'm encountering an error. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Jun 16, 2023 9:09:37 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.48.3
Jun 16, 2023 9:09:37 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to load plugin class (mapsforge-map-writer-master-20230526.153436-506.jar).
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.TaskRegistrar.loadPluginClass(TaskRegistrar.java:340)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.TaskRegistrar.loadPlugin(TaskRegistrar.java:319)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.TaskRegistrar.initialize(TaskRegistrar.java:84)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:81)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapsforge-map-writer-master-20230526.153436-506.jar
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.TaskRegistrar.loadPluginClass(TaskRegistrar.java:338)
    ... 11 more
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mapsforge-map-writer-master-20230526.153436-506.jar* Something wrong there - that's not a classname. How are you running this?

Comment: osmosis -p plugins/mapsforge-map-writer-0.19.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar --rb file="ile-de-france-latest.osm.pbf" --mapfile-writer file="paris.map" tag-conf-file="tag-mapping.xml"

Comment: I don't know if I installed mapfile-writer plugin the right way, I installed osmosis with brew first, then I downloaded the jar for the mapfile-writer and placed it in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/osmosis/0.48.3/libexec/lib/default

Comment: f.q. name of the class required there not a jar file. I don't know how they know the classpath but they will have to